# Color scheme in BarChart3D

Tags: plotting

Hello fellow Mathematica users!
I am trying to plot a barchart 3d plot for some data. However, I am facing issues with colorscheme. For example consider the following code:

```
dta = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};


BarChart3D[dta, ChartLayout -> "Grid", ViewPoint -> {3.33, -8.26, 5.36}]
```

If[image: bar chart] you run the above simplistic code, you will see a 3*3 bar chart. However, in this plot, all the bars in the column have the same color. But I need same color bars in the row.
Can you suggest a way such that I have same color bars in the row?

Comment: Using `Transpose` :) : `BarChart3D[Reverse /@ Transpose[dta], ChartLayout -> "Grid", 
 ViewPoint -> {3.33, -8.26, 5.36}]`. More seriously, 1) I cannot find documentation describing `ChartLayout -> "Grid"`, and 2) using `ColorFunction` might be a possible way.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. @AntonAntonov, but this code still not generates plot with same color bars horizontally.

Comment: It does -- did you try it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
BarChart3D[dta, 
 ChartLayout -> "Grid", 
 ViewPoint -> {3.33, -8.26, 5.36}, 
 ChartStyle -> {Automatic, None}]
```

[image]

To remove the  background panels use `"Canvas" -> False` :

```
BarChart3D[dta, 
 ChartLayout -> "Grid", 
 ViewPoint -> {3.33, -8.26, 5.36}, 
 ChartStyle -> {Automatic, None}, 
 "Canvas" -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks @kglr, it is very simple and useful.

Comment: @physicsgeek, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible, *not very good*, solution via `Reverse /@ Transpose[...]`:

```mathematica
gr = BarChart3D[Reverse /@ Transpose[dta], Axes -> True, 
 FaceGrids -> {{-1, 0, 0}}, ChartLayout -> "Grid", Ticks -> All, 
 ViewPoint->
  List[8.90170545374032`, 3.8424205491683088`, 3.741048561323293`], 
 Boxed -> True]
```

[image]

The panels can be removed with `Rest` :

```mathematica
Rest /@ gr
```

Comment: Thanks again. Yeah, it works.

Comment: No problem! But there *should be* a more streamlined and better looking solution.